# Nock does not intercept call to 3rd party

Tags: javascript, mocking, automated-tests, web-api-testing, nock

I am trying to automate some REST services using SuperTest. The service is a POST call, which internally calls another third party service GET method. I am trying to mock third party services to improve test efficiency and reduce test execution time.
I am using **nock** to mock the third party service call.

My initial service call looks like -

```
curl -X POST \
  http://internal-url.com/path \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}'
```

This service makes a call to the third party service which looks like -

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://3rdparty-url.com/value1' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'key2: value2'
```

I have mocked the service using nock in beforeTest like -

```
nock('http://3rdparty-url.com')
    .get('/value1')
    .reply(200, 'domain matched');
```

When I make a call directly to this third party service using SuperTest, it is returning the mocked response. However, my objective is to make the POST call, and intercept call to the third party service with the stub, which is not happening. I have achieved similar thing in Java world using **WireMock**. Is it possible to do this using nock?

My test looks like -

```
var payload = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"};
describe('Test third party Service', function () {
    it('should return success on POST /path service', function (done) {
        supertest('http://internal-url.com')
            .post('/path')
            .send(payload)
            .expect(200)
            .expect('Content-type', /application\/json/)
            .expect(function (response) {
                console.log(response.body);
                //test fails as third party server is not available and mock doesn't intercept
            })
            .end(done);
    });
```

Comment: It is possible with nock and your example is correct. There must be something else set up incorrectly in your tests. It might be helpful if you include your code using supertest to call your local app.

Comment: @MattR.Wilson - updated the test

Comment: What steps have you taken to verify that the request being sent from your internal app is identical to the curl GET request you posted above? Also, is the internal app running in the same Node process as the test?

Comment: @MattR.Wilson -  I have verified the application log, which shows the exact CURL as I’m using. On the second point the application and the tests are running on the different Node processes. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nock works](https://github.com/nock/nock#how-does-it-work) by monkey-patching functions from Node's http and https modules in the memory of the current process. This means that the calls to Nock must be made in the same process as the one making the requests.

In your case, whatever is running the app for "internal-url.com" needs to call nock. A common convention with nock and supertest is to run an instance of your internal app in the same process as the tests. [Supertest examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#example) show how to do this with a framework like Express.

Comment: I think it's better to give some context on what you mean rather than just URL references. What happens if that URL is broken or ceases to exist?‍♂️

Comment: The entire first paragraph is context that answers the specific question about Nock.
The second paragraph was meant to be helpful in leading the OP in the right direction for their use case, which happened to be Supertest. As this question wasn't about Supertest, I purposely didn't copy/paste code from its readme as it was off topic.